# Can a tiger do Kung-Fu?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Other than the sheer absurdity of it (read: real world limitations), is there anything stopping a multiclass Monk/Druid from using flurry of blows while in wild-shape?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let's look at [Flurry of Blows](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk#TOC-Flurry-of-Blows-Ex-):

> He may make one additional attack using any combination of **unarmed
>   strikes** or attacks with a **special monk weapon** as if using the Two-Weapon
>   Fighting feat

The [Feral Combat Training feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/feral-combat-training-combat) will add a natural weapon to the monk weapon lists.

However. Tigers, as any other creatures, possess an Unarmed Strike. This means your Improved Unarmed Strike is relevant, and everything under "[Unarmed Strike](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk#TOC-Unarmed-Strike)" in the monk description is relevant too. Including and especially:

> A monk's attacks may be with fist, elbows, knees, and feet. This means
>   that a monk may make unarmed strikes with his hands full.

So even though you have natural weapons, you can decide not to use them and do a normal Flurry of Blows, dealing damage as shown under "Unarmed Damage" (using your modified size).

### So yes, a tiger can do kung-fu (a T-Rex too).

Comment: You can also add natural weapon attacks after the Flurry, as secondary natural weapons. But I think you should cite the claim that all creatures have an Unarmed Strike.

Comment: This post seems to agree that all creatures have an unarmed strike: http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=178554. This post also talks about unarmed strikes and natural weapons: http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20070403a

Comment: @KRyan Actually, that's interesting, as I can't find a definite answer on that point. I find both arguments for (the ones I relied on initially, and quoted by Cypher), and elements against. Should we open a new question about "Do animals have an Unarmed Strike?" ?

Comment: If they did, then per http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/17163/140 every critter would be getting some spare attacks even if not a monk. Seems clearly against design intent since every stat block ever hasn't listed unarmed along with natural attacks for oh say any kind of critter ever.

Comment: On another hand, Unarmed Strikes are mentioned only when relevant (or should we assume that [a drow](https://sites.google.com/site/pathfinderogc/bestiary/monster-listings/humanoids/drow-common) doesn't have any Unarmed Strike?). That's where the problem lies: is there a way, anywhere, to prove that a drow or a vampire has an Unarmed Strike, and a tiger doesn't?

Comment: @mxyzplk: No, it would only be relevant for creatures that are Monks. You can only use Claw and Unarmed Strike if you can make UAS that are not punches, which is a special class feature of the Monk.

Comment: UAS aren't mentioned in Drow entries and the like because they wouldn't be optimal. Without the proper feats, it would be considered dual-wielding (assuming it also attacks with the weapon), which without the proper feats would impose a -4/-8, making it pointless, even if you do get the extra attack. For an animal, it would be even worse, as they would then make all their natural attacks as secondary attacks, and be fighting without proper weapon proficiency (as UAS is a simple weapon, for purposes of proficiency.) The negatives to hit would be huge, and a waste of time for most animals.

Comment: @Scrollmaster Is there anything you want to preserve from these comments? They should probably get cleared away.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot usually use natural weapons as part of a flurry of blows, so by default the answer is no.  Luckily Paizo has come to  your tiger-monk's rescue with the [Feral Combat Training feat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/feral-combat-training-combat) in Ultimate Combat, which explicitly allows this. See [Can I use a full attack and natural attacks in the same round?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/16924/can-i-use-a-full-attack-and-natural-attacks-in-the-same-round) for how natural attacks and monk flurries interact usually.

Comment: I'm not asking if I can flurry and make my natural attacks, I'm asking if there's anything preventing me from using flurry of blows, like normal, just while in the form of a tiger.

Comment: Take a look at the FAQ/errata on the Feral Combat Training feat. It states that you cannot use your Natural Attacks as part of a flurry of blows. So *yes* you can use your flurry of blows as a tiger. I think it becomes a question of how much damage. The Tiger has a 1d8 paw and a 2d6 bite. You clearly cannot do a flurry of blows with the bite (_unless you have the feat_). So you do a d8 of damage with the paw. Given that the Monk already does a d6 or more, this seems pretty reasonable.

Comment: That Natural Weapons+Flurry of Blows question has some pretty deep and specific rules analysis going on, and it's specifically using the 3.5 rules. It may or may not apply to *Pathfinder*.

Comment: @GatesVP Actually, the unarmed damage (without the feat) would not be based on the paw, as a monk damage is not based on a base punch damage. You would just use your level+size to determine the damage value.

Comment: @mxyzplk Is there anything you want to preserve from these comments?