# How do natural and weapon attacks mix?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat

I have a level 1 Synthesist Summoner.

Since he has the Quadruped base Eidolon, when fused, my Summoner has a bite attack (Primary). In addition, I have spent evolution points on a tentacle (Secondary). Finally, my Synthesist carries around an Axe, with which he can make weapon attacks.

If I were to use the Full-Attack option, what attacks could I make, and at what penalties? Let's assume I want to always use the Axe, where possible.

How does this interact with the eidolon's natural attack limit? (3 at first level)

Comment: Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/16924/can-i-use-a-full-attack-and-natural-attacks-in-the-same-round

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use your manufactured weapon as normal for full attacks – iteratives, Two-Weapon Fighting, Flurry of Blows, whatever.

You then get any natural weapon attacks, all treated as secondary attacks (−5 penalty to attack, Strength to damage halved), **unless** the limb involved in the natural attack was already used for a manufactured weapon. This usually means no Claws, but other restrictions could imaginably come into play.

Worth noting that the Multiattack feat reduces the penalty on secondary attacks to −2 instead of −5. Can be worth it if you’ve got three or more.

Comment: So since I have a Bite and a Tentacle, I can make a full attack (1 attack) + bite + tentacle (at BAB -5). Does the Fused Eidolon's Natural Attack limit (3) apply to manufactured weapon attacks?

Comment: @RavenDreamer No, it does not apply to manufactured weapon attacks. "This indicates the maximum number of natural attacks [...] This does not include attacks made with weapons." [Source](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/summoner/eidolons#TOC-Max.-Attacks)

Comment: @RavenDreamer If you're attacking with the axe, your bite will also be treated as a secondary attack (BAB -5). Your primary natural attack(s) become secondary if you are also attacking with a weapon(s).

Comment: You should probably correct your answer " A monk cannot use any weapon other than an unarmed strike or a special monk weapon as part of a flurry of blows. A monk with natural weapons cannot use such weapons as part of a flurry of blows, nor can he make natural attacks in addition to his flurry of blows attacks."

Comment: @DanceSC - "as a part of a flurry..." - combining natural attacks would mean they are secondary and not a part of the flurry, as normal for combining natural attacks with [whatever].

Answer (score 2):

To answer the latter part of your question, no your iterative attacks don't take away from the potential number of natural attacks you can perform.

Meaning that if you were a level 1 Synthesist, bipedal, with all 3 evolutions in tentacle.

Then you could swing your great ax (as your 1 and only iterative attack from your BAB) then get 3 tentacle attacks as secondary attacks -5 from BAB, x.5 str (meeting the max of 3 natural attacks that you get)

Comment: @Spellcaster I’ve rolled back your edit that supposedly “fixed” the grammar, because your first change actually broke the grammar, and your second change didn’t fix anything, it just went from one valid spelling to another (and we prefer to leave authors’ preferred spelling for words in place). @ reviewers, please review more carefully in the future, that edit should not have been approved.