# How does a Ghostly Arm (graft) interact with Two-Weapon Fighting?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, touch-attacks, incorporeal

According to Libris Mortis (p. 80):

> ...the grafted creature can use the ghostly arm to deliver an incorporeal touch attack that deals 1d6 points of damage, the equivalent of a ghost’s corrupting touch attack. Treat the arm as a secondary weapon, but because it is incorporeal the arm has no Strength score and therefore gains no bonus or penalty on damage rolls from the user’s Strength.

If I already have 2 weapons and attack with them, using 2 weapon fighting will this give me a third (natural) attack? If i have 2 ghostly arms will it give me 4 attacks, and so on?

Comment: Edit the question such that it asks the single question you want to ask.

Comment: So your question has nothing to do with the ghostly arm per se, you are asking how to mix weapon and natural attacks? In that case I think this is a duplicate of http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/16924/can-i-use-a-full-attack-and-natural-attacks-in-the-same-round

Comment: Your title says "sneak attack." The body says a graft but then you talk about still attacking with two weapons. Can you clean this up and get to the heart of what you're doing and asking? "One arm with a weapon, one graft" - are you asking if this graft can wield a weapon so you can 2wf, or if you can 2wf with a weapon and this arm, or if you can attack with this arm in addition to a normal (one-handed?) attack routine, or something about sneak attacks you don't really get to mentioning?

Comment: Are you using the graft in some way to give you arms in addition to your normal 2 (not the default use, grafts replace limbs)?

Comment: I took "Sneak Attack" out of the title. I do not know if his DM is using any house rules about the grafts as limb replacement, or if he is simply adding ghostly limbs in addition to his standard limbs. This is still unanswerable (in my opinion) despite the edit to the question.

Comment: @Ruut Based on activity in chat just before this was posted, the asker was simply unaware that grafts were replacement limbs, not bonus limbs.

Comment: Where in libris mortis does it state that they are replacments? The only thing i can find is about a character ability.

Answer (score 2):

Grafts replace existing limbs, they don't give you an extra limb. So, you will be trading your second weapon *(and the arm you wield it with)* for a ghostly arm.

On the plus side, it is incorporeal and uses touch AC, so it will hit armoured or incorporeal enemies more easily.

On the minus side, you can't do *anything* physical with your new arm.

You might be better off with a *Ghost Touch* weapon.

Comment: Where in libris mortis does it state that they are replacments? The only thing i can find is about a character ability.

Answer (score 0):

The type of attack is "incorporeal touch" just like most incorporeal undead have. As you can deal damage with it, it allows you to make Attacks of Opportunity and threaten the areas into which you can make attacks.

Regarding the use of two-weapon fighting, if you normally have two attacks with your main weapon, you would get another attack with the incorporeal touch as an off-hand weapon, with all the rules and penalties for fighting with two weapons.

The rules don't exactly state how incorporeal creatures deal with incorporeal touch spells. (The only case in the SRD is specifically about ghosts, which have special rules about incorporeality.) However, the *spectral hand* spell creates an incporporeal hand that is made for the exact purpose to deliver touch spells at a distance. I would accept that as precedent that an incorporeal hand can deliver touch spells.

Finally, the incorporeal hand can be used with the Weapon Finesse feat. An incorporeal touch should be a natural attack and the description of Weapon Finesse states that natural attacks are always light weapons.

Comment: Could you edit this into a single answer, such that it has a cohesive flow?

Comment: Im more of asking, would the 2 attacks from two weapon fighting cause disturbance with the 2 newly gained natural attacks? What would the end amount of attacks be?

Comment: @Simon Is your DM allowing grafts to be in addition to limbs currently possessed? Or is he treating the grafts as intended, as replacement limbs?